# Scaling facets to fit the data and use maximum available space using FacetGrid in seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, scaling, facet-grid

I am working with the `FacetGrid` example presented [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html) where `FacetGrid` object is initialised with the code snippet below, resulting in the plot following.

```
# Initialize the FacetGrid object
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", height=2, aspect=10, palette=sns.color_palette("Blues", 1))

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)
```

[image]

I have added value labels to all facets and I would like to modify it further to scale each of the facets, as I have a lot of cases where the values go beyond the maximum space of the facet, and some cases where it is not possible to see the data, due to the values not being dense enough. The first group of cases is presented below, and you can see how the labels go beyond to the next facet, reducing the clarity of the plot.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a separate scaling of each facet, with the values marked, and the maximum value placed on the top of the available facet space.

Comment: What happens if you set `sharey=False` in the FacetGrid?

Comment: I tried it before writing this post and it did not solve it, maybe because other factors are impacting it. I will update the question with the relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, once commenting out the line below, the facets are not overlapping anymore:

```
# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)
```

Furthermore, following the suggestions in the comments, I set the value to a positive number to bring the facets closer to each other, but without introducing the overlaps between the labels of the neighbouring facets. I found the value of `0.2` to suit the needs well:

```
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.2)
```

Then `sharey=False` argument in `FacetGrid` constructor is working. It looks much cleaner, but the values are not all the way to fill the whole available space, but that is maybe intended.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", height=2, aspect=10, sharey=False, palette=sns.color_palette("Blues", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Of course you may set `subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)` to any other value you like. I would start at `hspace=0` and increase it until you're satisfied.

Comment: The problem is that I am generating those plots for many different quantities, so I could potentially spend a lot of time fine tuning them and probably never arrive at a value that would satisfy all.

Comment: Not sure why different quantities would require different values of `hspace`. What I meant is to set it to some value once and use that same value throughout.

Comment: Some of the quantities are very dense around a certain value and they were causing problem exceeding to the neighbouring facets.

Comment: If you set `hspace=0` that should never happen.

Comment: But then I am actually getting labels to overlap like in the picture from the question.

Comment: Well, there should only ever be one single label overlapping. To avoid that as well, you can increase `hspace` slightly. The best value will depend on the number of facets and the fontsize in use.